# How to Fire event of choice (keypress or blur) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, blur, focusout

```
$("#var").keypress(function (a) {
        //line 1
        //line 2
        if(condition) {
            functionToBecalled(params);
        }

    }).blur(function (a) {
        //line 1
        //line 2
        if(condition) {
            functionToBecalled(params);
        }
    });
```

#var is the text-field name.
The function "functionToBecalled()" performs get operation using XHR in another file.Same statements are to be performed in both cases.

I want the data to be retrieved as the user presses enter or clicks outside the text-field.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you want to fire the keypress/blur event? Or simply call the funtionToBecalled when the events _are_ fired? The lattar one you already have.

Comment: user will either press enter or click outside of the textfield ..I want both the events to be working

Comment: try without chaining methods

Comment: Only keypress is working

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your code:

```
... }.blur( ...
```

should be

```
... }).blur( ...
```

since .keypress( ... ) is a function and you are chaining .blur after .keypress.

Comment: Consider removing the very last parenthesis.

Comment: It should work, I have tested it. Have you tried clearing browser cache?